# Why do all my files get read as javascript - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am attempting to get into backend webdev but this is becoming way more complicated than I thought. I am building a simple app that accesses a Web API and modifies a webpage. My problem is that all my files, javascript, html, or css are all processed as javascript, and I am pretty sure this is a simple fix but I don't even know where to start.

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') return; // url to icon that is not stored locally so throws error to server

    let requestURL = req.url.length < 20 ? __dirname + req.url : req.url;

    console.log("### " + requestURL + '\n');
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.readFile(requestURL , function (error, data) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.writeHead('Error: File Not Found');
        } else {
            res.write(data);
        }
        res.end();
    });
    
});
```

This is the code to my server file. There are a few things that I did to make it work that I know are just bypassing the problem, like the < 20 length thing in the 4th line. I did this because my html was being read as js so this fixed it, but today I tried to add styling and my css is being processed as js as well and is hitting an error in the first line because obviously css syntax is different than js syntax. I asked a similar question earlier and the answer was that I needed to handle multiple responses. This may still be the issue but that is too high level for me to understand what that means, so if you could break this down in terms that someone with pretty much no backend experience can understand, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

I am using node btw.

Comment: What is calling your endpoint?

Comment: @Deadron I have a function in my javascript app.js file and it works fine, it is pretty much copy and paste from the api documentation so I don't think my problem is in how I'm calling it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: This `if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') return;` is evil.  You need to send a response to every incoming http request.  You can send a 404 status if you want.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking into using express.js here https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html then you can use this for static files

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: Ok I will look into that. Thanks!